# trying to send data from one script in python to another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I am trying to write a script so when an IP address can't be seen a message gets sent with a telegram letting me know which computer is offline

I have been able to get the telegram side working but i have not been able to pass the data from the main script where it is testing the ip address , at the moment i have test data in there but i would like it to send the error with the computer name

main.py

```py
import socket
import ssl
from datetime import datetime
import pickle

import subprocess
import platform

class Server:
    def __init__(self, name, port, connection, priority):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port
        self.connection = connection.lower()
        self.priority = priority.lower()

        self.history = []
        self.alert = False

    def check_connection(self):
        msg = ""
        success = False

        now = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

        try:
            if self.connection == "plain":
                socket.create_connection((self.name, self.port), timeout=10)
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                success = True
                self.alert = False
            elif self.connection == "ssl":
                ssl.wrap_socket(socket.create_connection((self.name, self.port), timeout=10))
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                success = True
                self.alert = False
            else:
                if self.ping():
                    msg = f"{self.name} is up. On port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                    success = True
                    self.alert = False
        except socket.timeout:
            msg = f"server: {self.name} timeout. On port {self.port}"
        except (ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            msg = f"server: {self.name} {e}"
        except Exception as e:
            msg = f"No Clue??: {e}"

        if success == False and self.alert == False:
            # Send Alert
            self.alert = True
            import tg_start
            tg_start.send_message("Happy days")

        self.create_history(msg, success, now)

    def create_history(self, msg, success, now):
        history_max = 100
        self.history.append((msg, success, now))

        while len(self.history) > history_max:
            self.history.pop(0)

    def ping(self):
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower(
            ) == "windows" else 'c', self.name), shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
            if 'unreachable' in output:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        except Exception:
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        servers = pickle.load(open("servers.pickle", "rb"))
    except:
        servers = [
            # Server("ifmc-repserver", 80, "plain", "high"),
            # Server("ifmc-repserver", 80, "plain", "high"),
            # Server("ifmc-repserver", 465, "ssl", "high"),
            # Server("ifmc-repserver", 80, "ping", "high"),
            Server("ifmc-repserver", 80, "ping", "high")
        ]

    for server in servers:
        server.check_connection()
        print(len(server.history))
        print(server.history[-1])

    pickle.dump(servers, open("servers.pickle", "wb"))
```

and tg_start.py

```py
import requests

message = "global"
alert = ""

def send_message(text):
    global alert
    global message
    print ("this is text messsage" + " " + text)
    #text = "Superman"
    alert = text
    print("Sending ALERT ...")
    token = "token"
    chat_id = "chat_id"
    print("test message" + " " + alert)

    url_req = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" + "?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + alert

    print(url_req)
    #results = requests.get(url_req)
    results = requests.post(url_req) # this request is a post, not a get

    print(results.json())
    # text = "my name" + text


send_message(alert)
```

Comment: but what's the problem? are you getting an error on telegram side?

Comment: Hi when i do the test from the tg_start the message sends to telegram with no issues and then i remove the test value and run it from main.py and it doesn't send anything no error

Comment: I tested your code, and it worked with a minor modification: You need to send a POST request to the telegram endpoint, not a GET. Also, you shouldn't use global variables if you're using local variables to the function (text argument). Change requests.get to request.post and that should work.

Comment: Hi mate thanks for that if its ok can you please send me back my code with what you changed i am dyslexic and exmples are easier to deal with, thanks so much

Comment: In that answers your quest, remember to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code worked with a slight change, sendMessage require a POST request, not a GET request.

```py
def send_message(text):
    global alert
    global message
    print ("this is text messsage" + " " + text)
    alert = text
    print("Sending ALERT ...")
    token = "token"
    chat_id = "chat_id"
    print("test message" + " " + alert)

    url_req = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={alert}"

    print(url_req)
    results = requests.post(url_req) # this request is a post, not a get
    print(results.json())
    # text = "my name" + text
```

Comment: I changed the code mate and doesn't send any thing i might be doing something wrong i guess

Comment: what's the error you're receiving? I tried your code changing the token and chat_id to mine and worked perfectly. I've modified the url_req a bit, maybe you're concatenating wrong types. Use the edited answer

Comment: I changed the code mate and doesn't send anything i might be doing something wrong i guess, i made the edit about in my old code

Comment: Remove the file servers.pickle in your current directory. I don't know what are you doing with it, but if the file already exists, no message is sent. Remove it and execute the code again with the code I've given to you. That should work. I have tested with my bot token and chat id.

Comment: I'll use your token id and chat id to show that it works, however, remove that sensitive information from your question,

Comment: Hi mate thanks for that i must have forgot to remove it but now i cant edit again, 

Where are you running the code from main.py or tg_start.py because when i run it from main it doesnt send anything with telegram

Comment: I created two temporary files in my /tmp folder, main.py and tg_start.py. I executed it with "python main.py", removing any "servers.pickle" file there.

Comment: This is my part in main.py that should be calling the telegram 

so sorry amte i am sure i am doing something wrong 

        if success == False and self.alert == False:
            # Send Alert
            self.alert = True
            import tg_start
            tg_start.send_message("Happy days")

        self.create_history(msg, success, now)

Comment: I'm using the exact code you posted in your question, I haven't modified anything. I only checked that no servers.pickle file was in the directory where the script was called.

Comment: ok so i added a print in and this line isnt even been called 

        if success == False and self.alert == False:
            # Send Alert
            self.alert = True
            print("this is an alert")
            import tg_start
            tg_start.send_message("Happy days")

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Uy-euwk9xpKrx59ukwZybC9iyfQJqSU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I told you to remove file servers.pickle. If you don't remove it, it won't work. I don't know what are you doing with that file, but if that file exists, the condition is not met and the message is not sent

Comment: that file store the ipaddress to check as i might need to add more later and not hard code them in to the code, i need this

Comment: you are corrected i tested when removing the file and it worked but i need the file and i need to know which ip address or computer had the issue, thanks so much for your help

Comment: just letting you know i got it all working i completely changed the code but ill still give you a tick